# Call base class from a subclass

Tags: c++, superclass, method-call

Lets say we have this:

```
class A1
{
    public:
        void draw(){}
};

class A2
{
    public:
        void draw(){}
};

class A : public A1, public A2
{};

void main()
{
    A a;
    // I want to invoke the draw() of A1. How can I do that?
}
```

If I just do something like a.draw() it won't let me because both A1::draw() and A2::draw() match to this. What can I do in this situation? How can I call A1's draw() ?

Comment: What is `A` here? It isn't even declared.

Comment: Please try to at least compile your code before you post, this doesn't even make sense.

Comment: You realise you can't call A1's draw method without an instance of A1?

Comment: Misstype. My bad. I fix it now sorry!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write `a.A1::draw();`

```
#include <iostream>

class A1
{
public:
    void draw(){ std::cout << "A1::draw()"; }
};

class A2
{
public:
    void draw(){ std::cout << "A2::draw()"; }
};

class A : public A1, public A2
{};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.A1::draw();
}
```

[Live demo link](http://ideone.com/zwdD7Q)

Comment: Its not. I edited the post. I forgot to add something. Check again

Comment: @TheCrafter: how about now ?

Comment: Yes it works now. Thanks a lot. I understand how to specify which one to use. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

if you wish to call draw() of A1, you can declare an object of A1 and call the function.

```
A1 a;
a.draw();
```

Similarly, with A2

```
A2 a;
a.draw();
```

However, I assume you with to call a function to call a base class function from a derived class object. So, here is the code for the same...

```
#include <iostream>

class Base{
  public:
    void foo(){std::cout<<"base";}
};

class Derived : public Base
{
  public:
    void foo(){std::cout<<"derived";}
};

int main()
{
  Derived bar;
  //call Base::foo() from bar here?
  bar.Base::foo(); // using a qualified-id
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You're problem lies in that there is no class hierarchy. You declared two classes: `A1` and `A2`. However, in main you declare an object of type `A`, which you never defined!</strike>

If you want to derive classes, say make `A2` a subclass of `A1`, then in your class declaration you would write `class A2: public A1`.

Don't forget to implement each instance of the draw method for each class if you want A2 to override the behavior of A1.

Use the scope resolution operator before the method to specify what class you want to call, ex: `a.A1::draw();`

Comment: That a was a misstype. Refresh the page and check my post again.

By the way I already got my answer. Thanks for your efforts though.